# What game (isometric perspective, showing buildings and trees) is shown in this newspaper snippet?

Tags: game-identification

In my local newspaper there is a blurry picture of a game. They didn't mention the game at all.

[image: a PC monitor showing a village with several buildings, surrounded by trees]

What game is shown here?

Comment: I love the pile of unknown chip crumbs on the desk, and the artfully arranged glass of pretzel sticks. Really adds to the decor.

Comment: This newspaper has the best resolution I've ever seen.

Comment: @JPhi1618 actually if you check the edit history, you can see that it was worse before but was edited with a better quality picture: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/311110/revisions

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The game is [Anno 1404: Dawn of Discovery](http://store.steampowered.com/app/33210/Dawn_of_Discovery/).

Here's a screenshot (that screenshot) from the game:

[image: A screenshot of the game "Anno 1404: Dawn of Discovery" which matches the one in question]

Comment: If it's a screenshot, then that means the game they're playing is the Photos app? :P

Comment: It is almost certainly photoshopped in. Taking good pictures of a computer screen is difficult. Also, the blur is all wrong.

Comment: You can tell by the pixels

Comment: This answer blew up overnight, nice! [If anyone wonders how I found it, here's a screenshot of me kind of live chatting about it on chat](https://s.ave.zone/cc0.png).

Comment: This makes me think maybe the suggestions pane when writing a question ought to do a reverse image search and prompt the user with 'does this answer your question'. That or have a bot that automagically does a reverse image search and posts an answer, then goes away if it's downvoted or a moderator steps in.

Comment: It looked a lot like Age of Empires. I'll try this one as well.

Comment: @mattdm Yup, Moire patterns are formed, because of the interferance between the pixel grid in the camera sensor, the computer screen, and also by the device you are viewing it on.

Comment: @Noah That, and lighting/dynamic range, and reflections....

Comment: @Ave That link is dead.

Answer (score 45):

Taking a snippet of the screen, like

[image]

And going to Images.Google.com, using it in a search, yields a [Wikipedia entry for Anno 1404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_1404), as the first result.

I would've done this in a comment, inspired by @Pharap, but my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: I'm not sure it was necessary to write out another answer for this.  This doesn't really provide anything substantial to the answer; it just explains the process of how the answer was found.  This is also explained in the comments of the other answer, so it's not like it's even new information.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. I think it serves as a more general solution to the question and an explicit example of what's suggested in another comment.

Comment: [You can just put the whole image on google and it still gives "anno 1404"](https://s.ave.zone/e22.png).

Comment: Would that be in part because of this page question now? I'm conflicted: on one hand this answer doesn't add anything, but demonstrating how to obtain the answer is worthwhile. It's reflected well in the saying "teach a man to fish..."

Comment: Bing has a crop tool that allows you to upload the entire image and just search for parts of that image.

Comment: @JMac I disagree, it's a great answer. As they say, give a man a fish and he'll eat for a day, teach a man to fish and he'll eat for the rest of his life. Teaching people how to solve their own problems is useful, especially when the solution is so simple. *And* it still answers the question.

Comment: @MilesRout I'm not saying reverse image search isn't a useful tool.  I'm saying in the SE format it's not really a good answer to take a question already answered and say "Here is the same answer; you can use this tool".  I could go through game identification threads and add a new answer saying what the game is and then explain a reverse image search.  I don't think it would be overly productive.

Comment: @JMac It's not like this answer bumps a whole lot of ancient questions, I don't think that would be appropriate. But I think this case it's probably okay, because it was answered on the same day. I don't think the first person to answer gets a monopoly on their answer and I think this answer is much more helpful.

Comment: (maybe adding an 'have you tried reverse-image-searching this?' popup when someone tries adding an image to a question tagged game-identification would be helpful)